# Windows 8 laptop doesn't receive IGMP multicast packets

Tags: multicast, windows-8

I am trying to use multicast to discover services like Bonjour printers etc.

These all work via Windows XP wired and wireless and Windows 7 wired and wireless.

The Windows 8 laptop (Dell XPS 12) only has wireless and doesn't receive the packets.

Is there some configuration/registry setting required to make this work or is it impossible in Windows 8?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/837abdae-2d31-422a-b3a0-f3035c7c85b7/igmp-multicast-disabled-on-windows-8 demonstrates similar behavior but no answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling IGMP Sniffing in the router made Windows 8 start to work.  Still don't know why Windows 8 was the only one that wouldn't work without this on the router.